# ReactJS Error: react/jsx-no-undef by react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to use menu bar in my project. First, I choose it from [React-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navbars) but program has show an error about 'react/jsx-no-undef'.

This is code from [React-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navbars) website.

```
const navbarInstance = (
<Navbar>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Nav>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
      <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem divider />
        <MenuItem eventKey={3.4}>Separated link</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar>
);
ReactDOM.render(navbarInstance, mountNode);
```

Comment: add this line `import {Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem,  Tabs, ButtonToolbar, Button, Table, ButtonGroup, Row, Col, Grid, Panel, FormGroup, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';`

Comment: @RJParikh I add that line but it still show an error.

'mountNode' is not defined  no-undef.

Did I forget something?

Comment: In place of "mountNode", you need to pass on the container name, in which you want to mount your "navbarInstance", please check that

Comment: To expand on @AyushSharma's comment, `mountNode` needs to be a DOM element. Usually these are selected with `document.getElementById('xx');`

Comment: @RJParikh, you should make your comment an answer, if you can expand it a bit too.

Comment: Yes I know @Chris. I am searching for better solution to help them.

Comment: I add `ReactDOM.render(navbarInstance, document.getElementById('root'));` but it show that it can't compile.

Answer (score 0):

For me works that:

Import ReactBoostrap and all their components using Destructuring:

```
import ReactBootstrap, {Jumbotron, Button, Col, Grid, Panel, FormGroup} from 'react-bootstrap'
```

Using:

```
class HelloWorld extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
            <Jumbotron>
                <p>Bootstrap is workings? </p>
                <div className="my-class-from-react">
                    <h1>Hello World from React.js</h1>
                </div>
            </Jumbotron>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Comment: I think that I forgot to import ReactBootstrap. Thank you for your advice.